Animated movie about thieves saving a princess
I watched this movie when I was younger, but I cannot recall the name.

Protagonist is a bank robber - the movie starts with a heist.
Princess is kidnapped, and is forced to marry some rich man.
The rich man owns a giant castle, of which a clock hand later kills him.
There are many action scenes, one involving ninjas ambushing the protagonist's car.

Background details:

Movie is foreign to the United States. I remember watching this dubbed.
It was a 2D feature length film.
I watched it in the early 00's, but it seemed like it was from the 80's or 90's.


What year\decade was it from, approximately? Do you remember the animation style? And was it short or feature length?

@Walt It was a 2D feature length film. I watched it in the early 00's, but it seemed like it was from the 80's or 90's.

This is The Castle of Cagliostro, (1979), directed by Hayao Miyazaki.

The Castle of Cagliostro follows gentleman thief Arsène Lupin III, who
  successfully robs a casino – only to find the money to be counterfeit.
  He heads to the tiny country of Cagliostro, the rumoured source of the
  bills, and attempts to save the runaway Clarisse from the Count
  Cagliostro's men.
...
The Count pursues Lupin and Clarisse to the face of the castle's clock
  tower. Lupin is forced to surrender the rings to save Clarisse, and
  they are both knocked into the lake surrounding the tower. After using
  the rings to reveal the secret of Cagliostro, the Count is killed by
  the mechanism as it moves to unveil the treasure.


Thank you for the answer. This has been on the back of my mind for a month now.
